# How to add nested links to Haml mockup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, haml

Trying to build app on Ruby on Rails - faced with haml.
Couldn't understand how to build nested each loops - always catch different errors.
here example of the code:

```
%table
  %tr
    %th Title
    %th Text
  - @articles.each do |article|
    %tr
      %td article.title
      %td article.text
      %td
        - article.tags.each do |tag|
        = link_to(tag.tag_name)
```

error:

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
```

and after it

```
end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

if I delete haml tags everything works. Can't understan what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: May be problem in this line ` = link_to(tag.tag_name)` , replace it with ` = link_to(tag.tag_name,"your path"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%table
  %tr
    %th Title
    %th Text
  - @articles.each do |article|
    %tr
      %td= article.title
      %td= article.text
      %td
        - article.tags.each do |tag|
          = link_to(tag.tag_name)
```